# PDF Typography : How to Calculate Tw & Tc for Paragraph design in pdf?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, typography

I am trying to form a paragraph in PDF and I have Completed Paragraph without applying Character spacing in it, am not satisfied with this situation.For **Left_Align & Right_Align** `"0 Tw 0  Tc"` is acceptable.But, in the case of **JUSTIFY** , i hope Tw and Tc needs to have some values.Meanwhile i have done justified paragraph by Calculating Tw alone.so i want to find Tc value ? i have gone through lots of specs and articles to apply text kerning but i couldn't get enough knowledge to do that.can any guide me through this?

```
0.3794089 Tw
0 Tc
(Ut dapibus semper ultrices. Aliquam) Tj
```

Comment: To make justification look good, is not trivial. It especially is not a matter merely involving the current line of text, the whole paragraph or (even better) page should look similar in respect to word and character spacing. If I had to do something like that, I'd try to understand how TeX does it.

Comment: @mkl:sorry to say this ,i didn't understand your comment.if i understand correctly you are saying that,"Default kerning is more enough for Justification".

Comment: Kerning and justification are different things altogether. You apply kerning because certain letter combinations require more or less distance inside than the distance implied by the information of the individual characters. Justification adds extra space everywhere to generate block paragraphs. And what I actually wanted to say is that good justification is not trivial.

Comment: @mkl: I thought kerning is `Tc` , that is the reason why i got confused brother and Now am clear.did u understood how TeX does it?

Comment: I only know that TeX does a good job of justifying text and that its source is available. I have not looked it up, but if I were you I'd look there for inspiration.

Comment: The solution already starts with good line breaking which does *not* mean putting as much as possible on one line and moving on to the next. Some links and book references concerning good line breaking can e.g. be found [here](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/typeset/).

Comment: @mkl:i am going through the link you referred me.I'll comment after i read the above.

Comment: I think it is even more important to read that article *Breaking paragraphs into lines* by *Donald E. Knuth and Michael F. Plass*. I have not yet seen it freely available, though.

Comment: @mkl : yes it is.but am getting some copy of those chapters in forums and some PDFs.I hope i'll find something and for last two-days i was busy with some other work so i couldn't continue this and again started working on Line Breaking. your replies are making my analysis better and better. [this link](http://defoe.sourceforge.net/folio/knuth-plass.html) has something.

Comment: @mkl: Hi,i have completed line breaking after a little analysis on the topics we discussed earlier.

Comment: Ok, great. You might want to write a short round-up and answer your question with that.

Comment: Sure ,i'll try my best.